# adding selected items to codeigniter cart

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating an online restaurant order system. I am using codeigniter. In the order page I have used the angular grid system which filters and sorts the items. 
What I want to do is create a checkbox in every row. The checkboxes I click the item corresponding to them should be added to cart. I am using codeigniter cart class. 
My code is as follow.

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-app lang="en"><head>
        <title>Wah Bhai Wah</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/animate.css">

           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/bootstrap.css">        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/java.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>queries/insert_into_cart.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on("click", ".view_link", function() {
     var id = $(this).data('id');
      $(".modal-body #itemid").val( id );

      var name = $(this).data('name');
     $(".modal-body #itemname").val( name );
     document.getElementById("descmodallabel").innerHTML = name;

      var image = $(this).data('image');
      document.getElementById("itemimagesrc").src = image;
     $(".modal-body #itemimage").val( image );

     var price = $(this).data('price');
     $('.modal-body #itemprice').val( price );

    });







        </script>
    </head>

    <style>
    .a
    {
        background-color:white;  
    }
    body{
    background: url("http://localhost/wah/images/slider/M3.png") fixed 100% 100%; background-size: cover; 
  }

    .d{
        background-color: green; height: 200px;
    }
    .c
    {
        background-color: yellow; height: 600px;
    }
    .item{
        background-color: white; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px; 
        box-shadow: 5px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 45px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 45px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 10px 45px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .main
    {
        margin-top:200px; 
    }
    .side-nav{background-color: white; padding: 30px; top:100px; }
    table{
     border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
td
{
    padding-right: 20px; padding-top:10px;
}

        .forms{background-color:white; padding-right:20px; margin-top:200px; position:static;}
    </style>

    <body>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalmenu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Menu</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>Item</td>
                  <td>Cost</td>
                </tr><?php
          foreach ($i as $items) {
            ?>

                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <img src="<?php echo $items->img ?>" height="50px" width="50px">
                    <?php echo " ".ucfirst($items->item_name); ?>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <?php echo $items->price ?>
                  </td>
                </tr>

            <?php
          }
        ?>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


        <div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cart</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table>
                    <tr><td>Item</td><td>Qty</td><td>Price</td><td>Total</td></tr>

                    <?php foreach($this->cart->contents() as $cart_items){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <?php $id = $cart_items['rowid']; ?>
                        <?php echo form_open('cart_test/update/'.$id); ?>

                        <td><?php echo $cart_items['name'] ?></td>
                        <td><input type="number" class="span1" id="qty" value = "<?php echo $cart_items['qty'] ?>" name="qty"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $cart_items['price'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $cart_items['subtotal'] ?> </td>
                        </tr>  
                        <tr>
                             <td>
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>cart_test/delete/<?php echo $id ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</a>
                             </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </td>
                        </form>
                        </tr>

                    <?php } ?>
                    <tr><td colspan="5" ><hr style="background-color: #000000"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2">Item Total</td><td colspan="2"><b style="text-align: right"><?php echo $this->cart->total_items()?></b></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2">Bill Total</td><td colspan="2"><b style="text-align: right"><?php echo $this->cart->total()?></b></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="5" ><hr style="background-color: #000000"></td></tr>
                </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <?php
                    if($this->cart->total_items()==0)
                    {
                        ?>

                                <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>cart_test/proceed_to_checkout" class="btn btn-primary disabled">Proceed To Checkout</a>

                        <?php

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ?>

                                <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>cart_test/proceed_to_checkout" class="btn btn-primary">Proceed To Checkout</a>

                    <?php
                }
                    ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Wah Bhai Wah</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>main/order">order</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalmenu">Menu</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>main/logout">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Cart <b style="background-color:red; -moz-border-radius: 45px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 45px;
    border-radius: 450px; padding:15px;" ><?php echo count($this->cart->contents()) ?></b></a></li>



            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>




        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">


                   <div ng-controller="customersCrtl" class="main">

        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">PageSize:
            <select ng-model="entryLimit" class="form-control">
                <option>5</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>100</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Filter:
            <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="Filter" class="form-control" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
            <table class="table table-condensed active" style="background-color:white; border-radius:6px; padding:20px;">
            <thead>
            <th class="success">Item Id&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('id');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>


            <th class="danger">Item Name&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('item_name');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th class="danger">Item &nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('img');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th class="danger">Price&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('price');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th class="danger">Category&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('category');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" class="danger">
                    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#descmodal" data-id={{data.id}} data-name={{data.item_name}} data-image={{data.img}} data-price={{data.price}} data-toggle="modal" class="view_link">{{data.item_name}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#descmodal" data-id={{data.id}} data-name={{data.item_name}} data-image={{data.img}} data-price={{data.price}} data-toggle="modal" class="view_link"><img src={{data.img}} height="50px" width="50px"></a></td>
                    <td>{{data.price}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.category}}</td>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>cart_test/add_to_cart/{{data.id}}/{{data.item_name}}/{{data.img}}/{{data.price}}">Add to Cart</a></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4>No Items found</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">    
            <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>apps/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>apps/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>apps/app/app.js"></script>  

<!-- Button trigger modal -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="descmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="descmodallabel"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <?php echo form_open('cart_test/add_from_desc') ?>
      <input type="hidden" src="" value="" id="itemimage" >
      <img src="" height="200" width="300px" id="itemimagesrc"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="" id="itemid">    
       <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="" id="itemname">  
       <input type="text" name="item_price" value="" id="itemprice"> 
       <input type="number" name="quantity" value="" required> 
       </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
        </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



    </body  
></html>
```

Comment: What is the problem to create checkbox?

Comment: Problem is not to create the check box, problem is how to add selected items to ci cart which are selected by checkbox.